# Apache log has things I don't recognize that look dangerous

Tags: apache-http-server

My site host disabled my account after I exceeded my bandwidth.  This was odd, since the site is small.  I started looking into the logs and while I'm used to seeing attempts to find common endpoints that I don't have, I saw a couple things that were very troubling.  First:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 77597  100 77597    0     0   184k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  246k
--2019-10-13 11:49:21--  ftp://matei:*password*@tyger.ignorelist.com/tst.tgz
       => `tst.tgz'
Resolving tyger.ignorelist.com... 86.121.73.246
Connecting to tyger.ignorelist.com|86.121.73.246|:21... connected.
Logging in as matei ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD not needed.
==> SIZE tst.tgz ... 21765
==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR tst.tgz ... done.

 0K .......... .......... .                                53.3K=0.4s

2019-10-13 11:49:23 (53.3 KB/s) - `tst.tgz' saved [21765]
```

and

I've never seen these things.  I think I've been taken over somehow. How do I fix it?

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
Can't open perl script "bot.pl": No such file or directory
Can't open perl script "bot.pl": No such file or directory
sh: GET: command not found
sh: GET: command not found
--2019-10-15 22:14:04--  ftp://94.177.240.65/bot.pl
       => `bot.pl'
Connecting to 94.177.240.65:21... --2019-10-15 22:14:04--  
ftp://94.177.240.65/bot.pl
       => `bot.pl'
Connecting to 94.177.240.65:21... failed: Connection refused.
failed: Connection refused.
```

Comment: Sounds like someone found a way to use your webserver executing arbitrary commands (fetching files is one thing, I'm more concerned about what they would then do with those). Ideally, I'ld re-install a new instance of that application, then try to import conf/runtime data from a backup of your previous copy. Unless you're quite familiar with that application, I would avoid trying to clean it up. In any case: current version of your site is vulnerable: don't re-open it without at least an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Linux machine has been compromised through the Apache service.

> How do I fix it?

There is no simple fix, as you need to investigate your whole system for potential breach.

Here are some general suggestions:

- Upgrade Apache to its latest version (via `apt-get`).
- Upgrade all your packages (`sudo apt-get update`).
- Upgrade all your web CMS/frameworks which are in use (check for any known vulnerabilities).
- Scan your entire system for any existing vulnerabilities (e.g. malware scanners, antiviruses).
- Scan all your websites for any malwares and shellcode files.
- If you're using PHP:

  - Use a [PHP security scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3056150/55075).
  - Use a [Malware scanner for PHP-based websites](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/35002/3474).
- If you're using shared-hosting, contact the hosting company.
- Check your system for any extra unexpected users (`/etc/users`) or files (e.g. in `/tmp`).
- If you've confirmed the breach:

  - Change all the exposed credentials (access keys, passwords, etc.).
  - Save all the evidences in case you need them (IP addresses, logs, infected/malware files).
- After patching your systems, keep monitoring your logs for any further suspicious activity.

If you're not confident with above, contact the IT company which specialize in that.

See also:

- [DDoS attack, what is correct process to investigate cause?](https://superuser.com/a/888553/87805)